# Spring MVC jdbc template

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I am using spring MVC and JDBC template.

```
String SQL = "select * from storeTable";
```

Using the above SQL statement, and print all results on a web page, which works well. However, I have to use the below SQL statement, which should also be seen on web page.

```
String sql = "select * from storeTable where STORE_NO = ? and Register_NO = ?";
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Querying for a String:

```
String lastName = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "select last_name from t_actor where id = ?",
        new Object[]{1212L}, String.class);
```

Querying and populating a single domain object:

```
Actor actor = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "select first_name, last_name from t_actor where id = ?",
        new Object[]{1212L},
        new RowMapper<Actor>() {
            public Actor mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Actor actor = new Actor();
                actor.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                actor.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                return actor;
            }
        });
```

Querying and populating a number of domain objects:

```
List<Actor> actors = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select first_name, last_name from t_actor",
        new RowMapper<Actor>() {
            public Actor mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Actor actor = new Actor();
                actor.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                actor.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                return actor;
            }
        });
```

**For you it will be something like this.**

```
 Object obj = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            "select * from storeTable where STORE_NO = ? and Register_NO = ?",
            new Object[]{1212L,46575L}, Returning.class);
```

queryForObject or query depends what your sql will return. Returning class can be a simple class or a row mapper object like above examples and obj will be the class/List<> that mapper maps the result to. Modify it accordingly

Check out the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate)